# Process: StandardOutput

Tags: vb.net, tcl, stdout

I try to communicate between 2 processes, one written in `Vb.net` and the other written in `Tcl`. My goal is to start the program in tcl through *System.Diagnostics.Process()* and communicate with the standard output of `Tcl`.

```
Dim form As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
form.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput  = True
form.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError   = False
form.StartInfo.UseShellExecute         = False
form.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow          = True
form.StartInfo.Arguments               = myargs
form.StartInfo.FileName                = "wish.exe"
form.Start()

Dim output As String = Nothing

While Not form.StandardOutput.EndOfStream

    output = form.StandardOutput.ReadLine()

    If output.Contains("IMAGE=") Then
        ' Do stuff...
    End If

End While

form.Close()
```

It works, but I would like to send an info to my `Vb.net` program to tell it to stop like this :

```
If output.Contains("EXIT") Then
    Exit While
End If
```

And finally let my `Tcl` program redirect its standard output to my wish.exe console like this :

```
# communication with vb.net program
foreach prt $fileimage {
    puts "IMAGE=$prt"
}
# exit vb.net program
puts "EXIT"

# puts others 'info' in my wish.exe console
puts "info..." ; # problem here > 'info...' is not visible in my console
```

The problem I have is that when I exit my program, the standard output of `Tcl` is no longer redirected to my console...
**My question** : What is the best way to get out of my program without losing the standard Tcl output?

Comment: If you don't need a Tk GUI popping up, use `tclsh.exe` instead of `wish.exe`; it's much happier being run as a subprocess on Windows.

Comment: @DonalFellows I need Tk GUI

Comment: Have you considered, for the Tcl output you want on the console, to use stderr?

Comment: @glennjackman,No, I didn't really think that and it works even with a `try` block, I thought it would cause me an error... Sometimes Tcl is a mystery for me :) if I don’t have a response from `Vb.net` and this error is due to bad syntax  `.net` , I would use your solution... thank you

Comment: How about having the tcl app just output it's commands to a text file in the user's tmp folder, and have your vb program poll that text file for the commands it is looking to handle?

Comment: @J.ScottElblein this is a solution too, but I would like to avoid using a temporary file...thanks anyway

Comment: The only thing i can think of is you'd have to set your vb app as some sort of listener, almost like a server. Or you'd have to keep closing the vb app when it's done doing something, and restarting it with your tcl app each time, passing cline arguments to it.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein , like `socket` ? but I don’t know much... with `vb.net` & `Tcl` but I will try if you’re talking about that...

Comment: Yea, I could be wrong and a real vb *guru* might know of a way, but off the top of my head I don't see how you can keep passing commands to a vb app from another app w/out the vb app being some sort of server (some sort of listener). Now having your vb app doing the frequent *checking* of something else is no problem.